# Google sign in - how to add Games.SCOPE_GAMES_LITE?

Tags: android, google-signin

I'm trying to set up Google Sign In for an Android game. The sign in works fine and I can select a Google account and sign in. But when calling the Leaderboard, it shows me an error: the Games.SCOPE_GAMES_LITE scope is missing from the currently signed-in Google account. 
So I've been trying to request this scope when signing in - but if I do, the previously working sign in dialog from Google does not show up anymore. It doesn't give me any error, it just doesn't show. (Same, if I try to change the DEFAULT_SIGN_IN to DEFAULT_GAMES_SIGN_IN.) Any ideas? Similar questions have been asked here before, but no good answer as of yet...

```
public class SignInFragment extends Fragment {

private GoogleSignInOptions options;
private GoogleSignInClient client;
SignInButton signInButton;
private Intent signInIntent;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View signInFragment = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_signin, container, false);

    options = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_GAMES_SIGN_IN)
            .requestScopes(Games.SCOPE_GAMES_LITE)
            .build();

    client = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this.getActivity(), options);

    signInButton = (SignInButton) signInFragment.findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);
    signInButton.setSize(SignInButton.SIZE_WIDE);

    signInButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            signIn();
        }
    });

    return signInFragment;
}

private void signIn() {
    signInIntent = client.getSignInIntent();
    startActivityForResult(signInIntent, StaticResources.RC);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == StaticResources.RC) {
        Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
        handleSignInResult(task);
    }
}

private void handleSignInResult(Task<GoogleSignInAccount> completedTask) {
    try {
        GoogleSignInAccount account = completedTask.getResult(ApiException.class);
        updateUI(account);
    } catch (ApiException e) {
        Log.w(TAG, "signInResult:failed code=" + e.getStatusCode());
        updateUI(null);
    }
}

private void updateUI(GoogleSignInAccount account){
    //...
}
}
```

And this is where I get the error about the missing scope:

```
private void showScores(){
// If user did sign in previously, this returns the user's Google account
if (StaticResources.thisAccount != null){

Games.getLeaderboardsClient(this.getActivity(),

GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this.getContext()))      
            .getLeaderboardIntent(getString(R.string.leaderboard_highscore))
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Intent>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Intent intent) {
                        startActivityForResult(intent, StaticResources.RC);
                    }
             });
}
else{ //...
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem... My gradle file was fine, but from my manifest file was missing this:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID"
           android:value="@string/app_id" />
```

You can find your App ID when logging into Google Play Console --> Game Services --> "Your game" --> "Game Details", directly under the header (which is the name of your app)