# App closes when downloaded from Google PlayStore work with release apk

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games, google-play-console, app-signing

I added google play games to the my game which already published on Google PlayStore. And then some of my users who update app send feedback to me that app crashes.

I sent same apk to users and app is working properly. App crashes when downloaded from google playstore.

Also I use google app signing so that I have 2 finderprints and I added both fingerprints to the console.

I want to say again my app closes only downloaded from google play store for some users.

Is there any suggestions?

I get this logs from crashlytics.

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Games APIs requires https://www.googleapis.com/auth/games_lite function.
   at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:32)
   at com.google.android.gms.games.internal.zzg.validateScopes(zzg.java:30)
   at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.GmsClient.zaa(GmsClient.java:41)
   at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.GmsClient.<init>(GmsClient.java:27)
   at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.GmsClient.<init>(GmsClient.java:11)
   at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.GmsClient.<init>(GmsClient.java:13)
   at com.google.android.gms.games.internal.zzg.<init>(zzg.java:1)
   at com.google.android.gms.games.Games$zza.buildClient(Games.java:6)
   at com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApi.zaa(GoogleApi.java:93)
   at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.GoogleApiManager$zaa.<init>(GoogleApiManager.java:7)
   at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.GoogleApiManager.zab(GoogleApiManager.java:43)
   at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.GoogleApiManager.handleMessage(GoogleApiManager.java:173)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.base.zar.dispatchMessage(zar.java:8)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
   at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65)
```

My Client configuration

```
mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(context, 
    new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(
        GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_GAMES_SIGN_IN)
                    .build());
```

Comment: Double check that the app signing certificate (listed on the App Signing page) is correctly whitelisted for the right package name. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62148182/android-app-bundle-kills-google-play-games-integration-working-with-plain-old

Comment: Yes I linked my game with both upload certificate and app sign in certificate. There are two linked apps.

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicate to 
[Google Games APIs requires games_lite function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49656327/google-games-apis-requires-games-lite-function)

Note that DEFAULT_GAMES_SIGN_IN already includes SCOPE_GAMES_LITE.

Also you might want to check your AndroidManifest to make sure it includes your app ID correctly.
[Google sign in - how to add Games.SCOPE_GAMES_LITE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51401533/google-sign-in-how-to-add-games-scope-games-lite)

Comment: App works when loaded by using apk but closes when downloaded from google playstore so that I don't think the error is on my code