# Google Sign-In and leaderboard

Tags: android, firebase, google-api, google-signin, game-center-leaderboard

I implemented Google Sign-In in my app.

If I signing in just requestig email:

```
GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
          .requestEmail()
          .build()
```

then I logging in successfully.

But if I add Games.SCOPE_GAMES_LITE (this scope required for leaderboard API I implemented too):

```
GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
          .requestEmail()
          .requestScopes(Games.SCOPE_GAMES_LITE)
          .build()
```

Then I always get ApiException: 4. What I have at this moment:

- This happens in debug and release build variants.
- My application released and published in Google Play and linked with FireBase.
- My game service with leaderboard is published and linked with Firebase.
- com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID is already in manifest and it is correct.

What did I wrong?

Comment: Maybe this could help you  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51401533/google-sign-in-how-to-add-games-scope-games-lite

Comment: @ArpanSarkar unforntunality, it's not a solution. com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID is already in my manifest and it is correct